# Property does not override any property from its superclass in swift5

Tags: swift, core-data

This is my code 
import Foundation
import CoreData

```
public class SpaceItem: NSManagedObject, Identifiable {
    @NSManaged public var name:String?
    @NSManaged public override var describe: String?
    @NSManaged public override var imagename: String?
 }
```

and Xcode is giving the error "Property does not override any property from its superclass in swift5"
could any one help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove keyword `override` from `describe` and `imagename` properties and satisfy `Identifiable` `protocol` requirement as,

```
public class SpaceItem: NSManagedObject, Identifiable {
    var id: String

    @NSManaged public var name:String?
    @NSManaged public var describe: String?
    @NSManaged public var imagename: String?
}
```